# How to retrieve the date on which a post was moved to trash?

Tags: wp-query, trash

I need to retrieve a list of posts that are in trash based on the date on which they were trashed.

The following code allows me to retrieve posts that are in trash, but how to filter them by date?

```
    $options = array(
        'post_status' => 'trash',
        'post_type'   => 'post',
        'nopaging'    => TRUE
    );

    $wp_query = new WP_Query();
    $posts    = $wp_query->query( $options );
```

Comment: Did you try the [`date_query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Date_Parameters) parameter?

Comment: That will allow me to retrieve posts based on `created date` or `modified date`. But how to use `trashed date` with `date_query`?

Comment: `modified date` will be the date that WP trashed the post :)

Comment: @TheDeadMedic I have not tried the code yet, but when I look in the admin UI the Last Modified date is not updated when a post is trashed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When post is trashed, WP creates a meta field named `_wp_trash_meta_time` and it saves trashed time in that field. You can use that field to get trash time.

**Edit:**

Example:

```
$args = array(
    'post_status' => 'trash',
    'post_type'   => 'post',
    'nopaging'    => TRUE,
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'     => '_wp_trash_meta_time',
            'value'   => array( strtotime("last week"), date('U') ),
            'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
        ),
    ),
);
```

Using this, you can get trashed posts which are trashed in last week.